# Use functions from main file in imported file

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to build some python script. I have imported (import Handler) set of functions in my main script (start.py). In start.py I call one of the imported functions to dynamically import scripts from config (dir1). I need to use 1 function (message(self, text) what is in my main script start.py in class MyScript(Protocol)) in one of imported files from config.
So my directory structure is:

```
MainDir
  start.py (main script)
  Handler.py
  config.cfg
  dir1 (dir with plugins)
    HelloWorld.py (this needs to use function from start.py)
```

Can you help me, please?
Thank you.
EDIT:
Start.py is Twisted TCP server, I need tu use some twisted functions in my plugins.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder

Comment: The obvious solutions are (a) move those functions out of `start.py` and into a module that both `start` and the plugins can import, (b) make it so that `start` can be imported (that is, make sure you did the `if __name__` bit right, etc.), or (c) pass come collection of functions (maybe even the `start` module itself, if you really want) to whatever needs to call the functions. Is there a reason one of those doesn't work for you?

Comment: @suspectus: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: My start.py is a twisted TCP server, I need some functions (like send message to client) in my plugins. If I import it, twisted will start new server, so this is not suitable. How can I move function to send message to client outside of twisted protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple more options:

1. Pass the function as a parameter to the code that calls it (this might be appropriate if you need that code to call different functions is different situations).
2. Use python's -m option to load start.py as a regular module (i.e., python -m start).  Then you can import start and refer to its message function just like any other python module.